# Python squarerooting

Tags: python, calculator

I have a calculator using Tkinter(The entire code for the program is [here](https://github.com/SovietKetchup/calc-gui/)) but the squareroot function doesn't work.

```
  def calculate(self):
     """ Calculates the equasion """
     calculation = self.out_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
     try:
        eval(calculation)
     except:
        ans = "Error"
     else:
        ans = eval(calculation)

     self.clear()
     self.out_box.insert(tk.END, ans)

  def calc_root(self):
     """ Calculates an equasion with a root """
     import math

     self.calculate()
     num = self.out_box.get("1.0", tk.END)

     try:
        math.sqrt(num)
     except:
        ans = "Error"
     else:
        ans = math.sqrt(num)      

     self.clear()
     self.out_box.insert(tk.END, ans)
```

I have a button linked up to the calc_root() button. It seems that no matter what number (valid or otherwise) precedes the squareroot, it returns "Error" through the except clause.

Comment: I mean it goes to the except clause, therefore returning "Error"

Comment: You need to make num a float. I think you're getting it as a string right now..

Comment: `num` is a string.  You can't take the square root of a string.

Comment: Aside: using a bare `except:` basically means "whatever goes wrong, don't tell me, I don't want to know what the problem is".  That's almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert types:

```
num = float(self.out_box.get("1.0", tk.END))

self.out_box.insert(tk.END, str(ans))
```

Also your `try`-`except`-`else` doesn't make sense:

```
 try:
    math.sqrt(num)
 except:
    ans = "Error"
 else:
    ans = math.sqrt(num)
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
 try:
    ans = math.sqrt(num)
 except:
    ans = "Error"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Why do I need to convert the output? .insert allows for non string types to be passed.

Comment: But it doesn't know what's being given shouldn't be a string.